# cvBlobsLib with mingw

Tags: opencv, mingw, cvblobslib

Does anybody know how to build cvBlobsLib using MinGW? On official page ***http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib*** there is only instruction for VS.

There is also linux version of this lib **http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=cvblobs8.3_linux.tgz** , but its makefile cannot be used in windows as i see.

Comment: @rotating_image unfortunately, there is no cmake files in this lib

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/

Comment: @rotating_image thanks for help, but cvBlobs and cvBlobsLib are two **differnt** libs

Comment: ya thats true but both have similar functions to operate on blobs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use eclipse then you dont have a lot of work:
Create a new project, using MinGW toolchain.
Go to the project properties, and under C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols add the openCV library paths.
compile the project and it should be OK. 
Use this
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib#Build_intructions
if you have more problems (especially NOTE 3)

Comment: hmm, good idea. But there are some troubles. I've added openCV include and libs paths in "Paths and Symbols". These files displays in Project Explorer. When I build project, there are fatal errors such as: `fatal error: cxcore.h: No such file or directory`. Maybe I should change `#include "cxcore.h"` ?

Comment: Well, this means that the file cxcore.h cannot be found in the include paths...
You should perform a search on your computer for that file (to be specific.. it must be in your openCV library), and add it's path to the "Paths and Symbols"